Why does the number of permutations of these sequences with non-negative partial sums have such a simple closed form (m choose n)?
I've been thinking about a problem, and I think that I have a solution, and I'm not sure why it works. Looking for an intuitive (or just any) explanation.
The problem
Choose an integer $k>1$. For any length $m > k$ where $m \not\equiv k \pmod{2}$, we can construct a $m$-length list of integers that sum to $0$, as follows:
\begin{equation}
\{a_i\}_{i=1}^m = (k,\underbrace{1,1,\cdots,1}_{n},\underbrace{-1,-1,\cdots,-1}_{m-n-1}).
\end{equation}
In particular, using $n = \dfrac{m-k-1}{2}$ guarantees the zero-sum property.
Now, consider all permutations of $a_n$. How many of these permutations have non-negative partial sums? That is, for how many permutations $p(i)$ does
$\displaystyle
\sum_{i=1}^{j} a_{p(i)} \geq 0 \text{ for all } j\in[1,m]?
$
The solution (I think)
Having read through far too much random Catalan number, Dyck path, and related literature, it seems that one way of solving this problem is by analyzing each cyclic permutation of the list. In particular, every unique cyclic permutation can be translated into at least one valid permutation with non-negative partial sum as follows:
Since $k$ is unique, we can choose a linear representation of every cyclic permutation by fixing $k$ at index $1$. Let $\{b_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be such a linear representation.
Compute the partial sums $s_i = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{j} b_i$. If $s_{min}$ is the minimum of $s_i$, then the permutation
\begin{equation}
(b_{min+1},b_{min+2},\cdots,b_n,b_1,b_2,\cdots,b_{min})
\end{equation}
is a permutation with non-negative partial sums. In fact, one is generated for each index of $s_i$ where $s_{min}$ is reached. At a minimum, however, we are guaranteed $\binom{m-1}{n}$ cyclic permutations, each with at least $1$ shifting with non-negative partial sums, so $\binom{m-1}{n}$ is a lower bound on the number of such permutations.
Now, upon some OEIS lookups and python code (EDIT: @peterwhy gave an inductive proof below), I've determined that, in fact, the number of permutations with non-negative partial sums has closed form
\begin{equation}
\binom{m}{n}.
\end{equation}
Using Pascal's identity, I can see how since $\binom{m}{n} = \binom{m-1}{n-1} + \binom{m-1}{n}$, that the lower bound found using cyclic permutations agrees. However, I am not sure how the $\binom{m-1}{n-1}$ contributes.
Interestingly, in the case that $k=1$, the Catalan numbers agree with this closed form, if you consider that the cyclic permutations overcount by a factor of $n+1$, since $k$ is no longer unique. Because of this, I suspect that the $\binom{m-1}{n-1}$ term has some meaningful interpretation using cyclic permutations.
The simplicity of the closed form leads me to believe that there may be some intuitive combinatorial explanation, Pascal or not, though I'm not sure what that might be. Any ideas or interpretations that could help my understanding would be greatly appreciated.

In order to distinguish the $+1$ terms even when $k=1$, modify the sequence $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^m$ to:
$$\{c_i\}_{i=1}^m = (k+\epsilon, \underbrace{+1,+1,\cdots,+1}_{n}, \underbrace{-1,-1,\cdots,-1}_{m-n-1})$$
where $0<\epsilon<1$. Then a permutation of $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^m$ has all non-negative partial sums iff the corresponding permutation of $\{c_i\}_{i=1}^m$ has all non-negative partial sums.
This answer is not valid for the plain $k=1$ case mentioned in the question.

The subproblems
For $k\ge1$, $n\ge1$ (i.e. $m\ge k+3$): The last term (index $m$) can't be the $(k+\epsilon)$ term. The term following the $(k+\epsilon)$ can either have value $+1$ or $-1$.
Consider these two terms as one merged term to form a shorter sequence. The shorter sequence has length $m' = m-1$, with $n'$ and $k'$ as follows:

If the term following the $k$ is $+1$, then the new sequence has:
$$\begin{align*}
k' &=k+1\\
n' &= n-1 = \frac{m'-k'-1}{2}\\
m' &\ge k'+1\\
\end{align*}$$

If the term following the $k$ is $-1$, then the new sequence has:
$$\begin{align*}
k' &=k-1\\
n' &= n = \frac{m'-k'-1}{2}\\
m' &\ge k'+3\\
\end{align*}$$



The base cases
For $k=0$, $m=2n+1$, with one $\epsilon$ term: The number of permutations is the product of $m$ and the Catalan number $C_n$:
$$\begin{align*}
\text{Number of permutations} &= m \cdot C_{n}\\
&= (2n+1)\cdot \frac{(2n)!}{(n+1)!n!}\\
&= \frac{(2n+1)!}{(n+1)!n!}\\
&= \binom{m}{n}
\end{align*}$$
For $n=0$, $m=k+1$: The only valid permutation is for the first term to be the $(k+\epsilon)$.
$$\begin{align*}
\text{Number of permutations} = 1 = \binom m0\\
\end{align*}$$

Inductively, applying Pascal's identity with the two cases:
$$\begin{align*}
\text{Number of permutations} &= \binom{m-1}{n-1} + \binom{m-1}{n}\\
&= \binom{m}{n}
\end{align*}$$

I actually wrote out (almost exactly) this proof when grappling with the problem initially, just thought it would bog down the post! It's how I convinced myself that the closed form was actually valid; I'll edit the post to reflect that. I really appreciate your explanation, but I was looking for a combinatorial interpretation that is more straightforward.

@Quick_Fix Thanks for the feedback. I considered the inductive step here a combinatorial interpretation, by partitioning all the permutations according to the term after the $k$ to the subproblems. Though the $k=1$ case is not intuitive to me, probably because I haven't studied the Catalan numbers and their applications enough.
